# Delete Unused Catalog Product Images

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, ce-1.9.0.1

I have taken over a magento store that over 3 years has built up a large amount of product images that are no longer in use but were never deleted.

Is there a way i can delete all images that are no longer in use, whilst keeping all images that are being used? I searched for a module/extension but couldn't find one that worked with magento 1.9 community.

Comment: Magento doesn't do picture windows, sometimes other housekeeping optional such as old quotes... Which causes filesystem and database bloat. Which spawned the Image Clean module over on Connect for the first, various scripts for quote cleaning that depend on innodb delete on cascade to eliminate by past dates

Answer (score 7):

you can try the following shell script: https://gist.github.com/aleron75/07ab2a950b2e3429a820

I haven't tested it on v 1.9.x. yet

Note: **do a backup** before using it on a production environment and possibly **test it** on a staging environment before.

Hope it helps.

Kind regards,
Alessandro

Comment: I don't have access to shell, is there a way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Well, if you understand the underlying logic you can try to port the script in a controller action method.

Answer (score 4):

You could upload this script to the root of your Magento installation and run it even from your browser.

https://gist.github.com/JeroenBoersma/60a4acb8e56498bce41c

## Check if your attributes for media are having these ids.

If you forget this, you could possibly break things

```
cpv.attribute_id in(85, 86, 87)
```

It will create checksums to detect duplicate files per product and unlink these from the filesystem and database.

The second step is detecting file which are on the filesystem and not in the database anymore.

Used it from 1.7 and up, so it should work.

**If you are smart, I always recommend to create a backup first.**

Answer (score 2):

You can put in Magento root path [this PHP script](https://gist.github.com/acataluddi/e5887529981f67e03eb3ffd53a577bef) and call it from browser:

[image: Script Web Console]

The script will run by default in `dry-mode` for a safe test letting you actually delete orphans if everything sounds convincing.

Comment: this script display only unused image but not delete images from database...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend heading over to

**System -> Cache Management -> Flush Catalog Image Cache.**

This will remove all the generated images and then re-generate them when a user hits the site.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using this n98-magerun module called [EAVCleaner](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner#eav-cleaner-magerun-addon)

After installing, run the following command to remove unused product images

`n98-magerun eav:media:remove-unused`

An advantage of using this module over the other scripts is that it can delete a larger quantity of images. Most of the other scripts linked above will create an array of images, then delete. This will traverse the media directory and remove the unused image [when it finds it](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner/blob/master/src/FIREGENTO/Magento/Command/Eav/RemoveUnusedMediaCommand.php#L66-L94)

We encountered an issue where a client's product information management system was uploading new product images every day and the media directory ballooned to nearly 400 GB in size. Every other script we found tried to put the hundreds of image file paths in memory and would error out. This script did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Place the below script in magento root and execute

```
  <?php

  require_once("app/Mage.php");
  umask(0);
  Mage::app();
  $ob = new Clean();
  $ob->removemedia();

  Class Clean {

  function removemedia() {
    $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $select = $read->select()
            ->from('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery', '*')
            ->group(array('value_id'));

    $flushImages = $read->fetchAll($select);
    echo count($flushImages);
    $array = array();
    foreach ($flushImages as $item1) {
        $array[] = $item1['value'];
    }

    $valores = $array;

    $pepe = 'media' . DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product';

    $leer = $this->listDirectories($pepe);

    foreach ($leer as $item) {
        try {
            $item = strtr($item, '\\', '/');
            if (!in_array($item, $valores)) {
                $valdir[]['filename'] = $item;
                unlink('media/catalog/product' . $item);
            }
        } catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e) {

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

function listDirectories($path) {
    if (is_dir($path)) {
        if ($dir = opendir($path)) {
            while (($entry = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
                if (preg_match('/^\./', $entry) != 1) {
                    if (is_dir($path . DS . $entry) && !in_array($entry, array('cache', 'watermark'))) {
                        $this->listDirectories($path . DS . $entry);
                    } elseif (!in_array($entry, array('cache', 'watermark')) && (strpos($entry, '.') != 0)) {
                        $this->result[] = substr($path . DS . $entry, 21);
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($dir);
        }
    }
    return $this->result;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

this way worked very well for me:

[github repository](https://gist.github.com/aleron75/07ab2a950b2e3429a820)

How to use:

Step 1:
Check directory size before execution

```
du -s
```

Step 2:Copy Mr. dajve code and create a file in

```
vi shell/shell_delete_unused_images.php
```

Step 3:
Execute file

```
php shell/shell_delete_unused_images.php
```

Step 4:
Check directory size after execution

```
du -s
```