# Storeviews not showing the same product image after import

Tags: import, product-images

Hi have a issue with the following issues which are connected to one and other.

- I cannot delete images programatically from my products.
- Images do show on 1 view and not on the other (same store/website)

I imported the photos via this function

Here are some screenshots

Default storeview: http://cl.ly/image/0p3L102K342h

storeview1:
http://cl.ly/image/1E3E270s393D

Storeview2: 
http://cl.ly/image/1u220a0R2D0w

```
public function UploadFoto($product, $fotos){
        $img = 0;

        foreach ($fotos as $foto) {
            Conn::log(' img:'.$foto, 'status');
            $img++;
            if(strlen($foto)>3){
                if($img==1){

                    $pathdeel = substr($foto,0,1).'/'.substr($foto,1,1);
                    $file = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog/product'. DS . $pathdeel . DS . $foto;


                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($file, array('thumbnail', 'small_image', 'image'), true, false); //assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
                }else{
                    $pathdeel = substr($foto,0,1).'/'.substr($foto,1,1);
                    $file = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog/product'. DS . $pathdeel . DS . $foto;
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($file, array(), true, false); //assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the images for each storeview separately.
Maybe your script is initialized in a store(view) instead of the admin as a script. That could explain the current behavior.

Start your script like this

```
// Initialize admin store
require('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
```

This way you are using the admin to set new data.

Magento does support out of the box deleting of images from a product, but it will not unlink these files on the filesystem.
Take a [look here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59650/delete-unused-catalog-product-images/60411#60411) for a script to to take care of that.

You could investigate *Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media* to take image import automation further.

Comment: Kom jou ook overal tegen haha... Thanks ik ga het vandaag even proberen..

Comment: Yes, success!!!