# How to delete unused images from my media folder?

Tags: magento2, php, product-images, script, media-images

I have more than 50,000 images in `pub/media` of products.

But there are so many unused images so I want to **remove all images which are not associated with any product**.

For Magento 1.9.x this can be a [Reference link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59650/delete-unused-catalog-product-images)
but I want the same PHP script for Magento 2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the Hackathon EAV cleaner module for this. After installation you can use the command `eav:media:remove-unused`

You can find it on Github: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner/tree/magento2

Comment: let me try it, will let you know.

Comment: It's working for me, Thank you so much :)

Comment: By the way, i've forked the repo so it is now possible to use composer installation: https://github.com/Vendic/EAVCleaner. The old repo seems to be inactive.

Comment: I've tried to install this. Composer doesn't find it and copying it directly doesn't work for me. Can you point me to or provide some simple instructions please?

Comment: Try `composer require hackathon/magento2-eavcleaner`

Comment: Problem was that there's a misspelling in the files, Hackaton instead of Hackathon! I've also found a couple of issues: first it doesn't cater for  any table prefixes (I prefix my table names with gs2_) and it doesn't allow for Windoze using '\' folder separators as opposed to '/' Linux. Finally, when clearing up images, the last part didn't run (the $this->getHelper('table') line). Is this important? It otherwise seems to have worked perfectly with those fixes.

Comment: Hi, i am using this extension but when i run command
bin/magento eav:media:remove-unused --dry-run
it show error message 
"The helper "table" is not defined."
please let me know how can i delete

Answer (score 3):

The easier method that I found is installing the module below and running these commands.

```
composer require ekouk/imagecleaner "dev-master"
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Run in check only mode which will report the number and size in Mb of unused images.

```
bin/magento ekouk:cleanimages
```

Then run this command to delete the files.

```
bin/magento ekouk:cleanimages -d
```

This module will only remove jpg, png, jpeg images from `pub/media/catalog/product` which are not referenced in the database. The default function without any switches will just report on unused files and NOT delete anything You must use the -d switch to remove files.

This module is provided free of charge with no warranty.

Please ensure you have a backup copy of your `pub/media/catalog` directory just in case anything does go wrong.

I found it and started to use it from [here](https://cannycookie.github.io/Mage2UnusedImageRemover/).

Comment: FYI, before "composer require" can succeed, you also need to add the custom repository into your composer.json file.  See the instructions linked at the bottom of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative there is this tool from Thomas Negeli that I used successfully to remove over 100 gb of unused images in Magento 2.3.6: https://github.com/ThomasNegeli/M2CliTools