# Magento2 : Manage and understand images of deleted products behavior?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, optimization, catalog-optimize

I'm trying to understand how M2 handle images of deleted products. If I delete a product (by admin or import/delete), all associated images in the `media/catalog/product` folder are still here.

In M1 and [Magento Image Clean](https://magecomp.com/magento-image-clean.html) installed, I was able to remove all images of a deleted product. The same extension [Magento 2 Image Clean](https://magecomp.com/magento-2-image-clean.html) for M2 fetch only 1 unused image.

After many reading, I found this [Magento 2, How to delete unused images using PHP script](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150929/magento-2-how-to-delete-unused-images-using-php-script). The solution seems to use the `php bin/magento eav:media:remove-unused` command of [magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner/tree/magento2) but still only 1 image found (same that the previous extension).

I try a script on my own who scan the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table, then scan the `media/catalog/product` folder to look for the difference but there is not. After digging into the database, I just realize that M2 keep records of old deleted product images in the DB.

**Question is:** how do you manage disk usage with all these useless images ?? My store has almost 4 collections/year and around 11.000 products to change... in only 6 months `media/catalog/product` folder size is around 6GB (without the cache) and still growing.

PS: I'm on a 2.1.9 version

Answer (score 8):

After many hours of reading, digging and testing, I finally understood how Magento2 handle products images.

- `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table content records of **all images uploaded** for products
- `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity` table content relation between **products ID** and **associated images**

Every extensions I found for cleaning the `media/catalog/product` folder does not work as I expect. (links in question) 
They compare the `media folder` with the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table.
=>  Found only images without any records in the **db** but not  **deleted products** one
I still don't unnderstand why Magento2 doesn't remove images while deleting product.
Based on [EAVCleaner](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/EAVCleaner/tree/magento2) modified, I developed a new `Command Line` with my needs, result :

```
Found 1,193.83 MB unused images in 6651 files
```

Flushing the images cache, Its finally **4,5gb** saved after only 1 year in production...

I share my code on Github [M2DeletedProductImage](https://github.com/cap340/M2DeletedProductImage.git)   for those who are looking for the same behavior. (not 100% safe, still don't really know possible issues of deleting old images)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the M2DeletedProductImage solution, it worked perfectly for me.

> Found 354495 files     23,698.23 MB

However this tool did not fix another issue I was looking the solution for. I have some entries in DB tables:

```
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery-value_to_entity
```

for products I deleted long time ago and also the images are not present in the `pub/media/catalog/product`.

I also checked the `catalog_product_entity` and this products do not exist.

In catalog_product_entity the smallest number for entity_id (Product ID) is 2168 (The same in Magento Admin) but in at least the 3 other tables mentioned above I have entries for more than 100 entity_id(s) from 1 to 2167.

How can I fix this?

Comment: sorry no ideas... I'm just a self made, hours of digging but far away from a developper.