# Magento 2: Right folder to upload images

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, upload

I'm having product listing in CSV file. Please let me know right folder to upload product images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upload images in `var/import/images` as default upload directory.

Else you can have any custom directory in var or pub but then you have to mention it while import.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I upload in ``var/import/images``  and it automatically duplicated in "pub/media/catalog/product/.." and "pub/media/catalog/product/cache" folders.. I'm lossing my disk space. Please let me know how to clear disk space?

Comment: when you upload images through import first you have to place images in
'var/import/images' then magento will import it and placed all files to 'pub/media/catalog/product/' and magento will generate cache for all images. that is default process. If you do not have memory then please increase memory.

Comment: use this to remove unused images : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150929/magento-2-how-to-delete-unused-images-using-php-script

Comment: Thanks for your information. I had checked unused images, my uploaded all images are used. Let me know if image may be doubled in product folder?

Comment: install module and remove unused images. then you will save memory.

If it helps please accept answer.